# Laravel form drop zone

Tags: jquery, html, forms, laravel, dropzone.js

Okay, So i want two dropzones with different names in one form, the `$request->all()` gives me just a token.

What i have done :

```
<form action="{{route('FreelancerTestsubmit')}}" class="dropzone" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <h1 id="try-it-out">Try it out!</h1>
                <div id="dropzone">
                    <div class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="photo1">
                        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                            Drop files here or click to upload.
                            <br>        
                            <span class="note needsclick">
                                (This is just a demo dropzone. Selected files are <strong>not</strong>
                                actually uploaded.)
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <h1 id="try-it-out">Try it out!</h1>
                <div id="dropzone">
                    <div class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="photo2">
                        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                            Drop files here or click to upload.
                            <br>        
                            <span class="note needsclick">
                                (This is just a demo dropzone. Selected files are <strong>not</strong>
                                actually uploaded.)
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Jquery :

```
   Dropzone.options.photo1 = {
      paramName: "file",
      maxFilesize: 2, // MB
      accept: function(file, done) {
        if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
          done("Naha, you don't.");
        }
        else { done(); }
      }

};
```

Now the action leads to a controller method via post method and the `$request->all()` gives me just a `token`.

How can i get the photo name and its values via `$request->all()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dropzone doesn't use an input. So it won't appear in the request.
You could make a ajax request for every file.

Or check the wiki of dropzone: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

Comment: So there is no way to include an input type file ?

Comment: @Gamer Click the link! It is possible.